# Sharing folder with windows computer

Tags: raspbian, windows, file-sharing, share

I have edited this file sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf

and added the below configuration

```
[piShare]
comment=Raspberry Pi Share
path=/media
browseable=Yes
writeable=Yes
only guests=no
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
public=no
```

based on `public=no` it should ask me password, which it does but even after entering username and password I keep getting the below prompt again and again

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use your PC as the "domain" for logging in, you may have to click the "use another account" and just type in "pi" and your password, or (since it looks like your WINS name for the Pi is RASPBERRYPI) `RASPBERRYPI\pi` and your user name.

Comment: I have tried that already

Comment: You could use 'FileZilla' instead it can transfer files through ssh

Answer (score 0):

double check the /media location to make sure "pi" is the owner or has permissions to access the share.  you can check the log file /var/log/samba/log.(whatever log, probably VIKAS-PC) from the screen shot.
Does the share work when puplic=yes?

Answer (score 0):

Please run `testparm -s` and check the output for correctness, especially the `valid users` line. You don't seem to specify any users for your share in `smb.conf`. A common mistake is forgetting to configure samba users which is done with

```
smbpasswd -a user
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

```
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
```

Then run:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```